# How can I embed a graph from d3js with CSS

Tags: html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to fix a graph created with j3ds:

`var svg = d3.select("#box").append("svg")`

In a css class called box:

```css
.box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  font: 1px sans-serif;
}
```

With this conde it's appear nothing, I can't embed it in that box, would appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a css mismatch.

Your javascript uses `#box` but your css specifies `.box`

Answer (score 0):

It was one part of the problem. I've solved the other so I post becasue it can help someone.
I wanted a simple example so I didn't write any html on the body and because of this I didn't initialize the div class box in body so the final code is:

```
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    </div>

<script>   

var svg = d3.select(".box").append("svg")
</script>
</body>
```